# How to change the rotation order in cocos3d

Tags: rotation, cocos3d

I'm a fresh in cocos3d, now I have a problem.

In cocos3d, I want to rotate a node. I got the angles in x axis, y axis, z axis, then I used the property:rotation to rotate, like this:

```
theNodeToBeRotated.rotation = cc3v(x,y,z);
```

But I found out it didn't rotate as I expected, because the document said the rotate order is y-x-z.

I want to change the order to x-y-z. Can anyone let me know how?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to clarify further regarding the following: *"it didn't rotate as I expected"*

OpenGL ES (and ergo, cocos3D) uses the y-axis as up so the rotation order is still x-y-z. If you are importing a model, you then need to take into account the 3D editor's co-ordinate system and adapt accordingly.

If you are not used to working with three-dimensional representations, the leap from 2D to 3D can be a significant hurdle. Within Cocos3D:

- the x-axis is positive on the right and negative on the left
- the y-axis is positive upwards and negative downwards
- the z-axis is positive moving towards you and negative moving away from you

Envisage those three lines of axis, or even better, a piece of string.

If you are rotating around the x-axis, hold the string horizontally from left to right: the object would rotating towards you or away from you.

If you are rotating around the y-axis, hold the string vertically from feet to head: the object would rotate as if like a revolving door.

If you are rotating around the z-axis, hold one end close to your chest and the other end as far away as possible: the object would rotate similar to a clock face.

-- Update

I heavily wouldn't recommend changing the rotation order as it is the OpenGL standard to use Y-X-Z. If you wish to modify it, take a look at CC3GLMatrixMath and look for ***kmMat4RotationYXZ*** - there is also ***kmMat4RotationZYX***. If you want to have X-Y-Z, you would need to construct your own rotation matrix and update accordingly in CC3GLMatrix and CC3GLMatrixMath.

As a reference, you also have the [OpenGL Red book](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter03.html) - it should have some suggestions for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.In the document of CC3Node-property-rotation,it said "Rotation is performed in Y-X-Z order, which is the OpenGL default".So I hope to know ,is there a way to change the order,to performed in x-y-z order?

Comment: Updated answer to include details regarding CC3GLMatrix and CC3MatrixMath.

Comment: I am not asking you to create new tags. Look within cocos3d and find cc3glmatrix / cc3matrixmath